# Network Visualisation (Python/Excel)

Tags: python, visualization, matplotlib, social-network-analysis, excel

I have a large data set similar to that in the screenshot below:

[image]

and I want to visualise the whole data set like the diagram below (made with a lot of effort in PowerPoint!)

[image]

Is there any way to do this for the whole data set in preferably Python but if there is a way in Excel, that would also be great.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution in Python. It uses [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) to load the data from an excel file, [NetworkX](https://networkx.org/) to create a network from that data, and [gravis](https://robert-haas.github.io/gravis-docs/) to visualize the network. Disclaimer: I'm the author of gravis, an open source Python package for network visualization.

```
import gravis as gv
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')

x_scale = 100
y_scale = 60
colors = ['blue', 'orange', 'gray', '#ffcc55', 'lightblue', 'green', '#dddd00']

dg = nx.DiGraph()
entry_to_color = dict()
entry_counter = 0
dg.graph['node_shape'] = 'rectangle'
for i, col_name in enumerate(df.columns):
    col = df[col_name]
    for j, entry in enumerate(col):
        node = str(i) + str(entry)
        if entry not in entry_to_color:
            entry_to_color[entry] = colors[entry_counter]
            entry_counter += 1
        dg.add_node(node, name=entry, x=i*x_scale, y=j*y_scale, i=i)

for i, n_name in enumerate(dg.nodes):
    node = dg.nodes[n_name]
    color = entry_to_color[node['name']]
    node['color'] = color
    node['label_color'] = color

for n1_name in dg.nodes:
    for n2_name in dg.nodes:
        n1 = dg.nodes[n1_name]
        n2 = dg.nodes[n2_name]
        if n1 != n2 and n1['name'] == n2['name'] and n2['i'] == n1['i']+1:
            dg.add_edge(n1_name, n2_name, color=n1['color'])

gv.d3(dg, node_label_data_source='name')
```

Here's the output if you run that code inside a Jupyter notebook, although it could also be done in the normal Python interpreter:

[image: network]